# how to remove duplicate values from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am looking for the query, deletes the all duplicate values.

```
Example Table:

1 ABC
2 BBB
3 DAC
4 ABC
5 AAA
6 ABC

output required

1 ABC
2 BBB
3 DAC
5 AAA
```

thanks for your help, i Google it can't find exact solution.

Comment: Why `1 ABC` not `6 ABC`?

Comment: get any one of them....it was just an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do an actual `DELETE` operation of the duplicate values (while retaining the values having the lowest `id`), you can do it with the multiple table `DELETE` syntax:

```
DELETE a FROM tbl a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id, name
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY name
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.name = b.name
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

---

### See a [demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92119/1/0) of the `DELETE` operation

Comment: Are you sure mysql allows joining the same table in `DELETE`?

Comment: @zerkms, I belive it's only when you try to reference the same table in a WHERE **subquery** that MySQL would throw an error. I just tried to use `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tbl GROUP BY name)` and it gave me "*You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause:*". [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) says "*Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.*" which is what I believe that was referring to (my WHERE NOT IN query).

Comment: yep, that's strange. Because subquery can be rewritten to `LEFT JOIN` (not sure 100%, but I bet so)

Comment: @zerkms, indeed it is. I also tried it with a couple variations of correlated `NOT EXISTS`s, which I know sometimes gets rewritten as `LEFT JOIN`s... but still the same error every time.

Answer (score 2):

See @fvu answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249235/1166147

You can create a `unique index` that will **remove duplicates and prevent future dupes all at once** (MySQL 5.1 or higher):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE 'YOURTABLE' 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX somefancynamefortheindex (Col1ID, Col2)
```

Comment: Sorry... What does it mean "like we do in excel"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Tab` is the name of your table containing duplicates, create a temporary table `Tab_TMP` with the same structure of `Tab`.

```
-- assuming `Tab` has same schema
CREATE TABLE Tab_TMP (
  id INT(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(8)
);
```

Fill `Table_TMP` with all `Table` entries.

```
INSERT INTO Tab_TMP(id, name) SELECT id, name FROM Tab;
```

Delete entries from `Table`.

```
DELETE FROM Tab;
```

Insert in `Table` entries from `Table_TMP` using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

```
INSERT INTO Tab(name) SELECT DISTINCT name FROM Tab_TMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. load distinct data in a file and delete or drop your table

SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,col3,..coln FROM table name  INTO OUTFILE 'yourFilePathWIthFileName'

eg:
SELECT DISTINCT username,usernumber,usersalary,dateOFJoining,timeofJoining,datetimeOfJoining FROM asdf INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/ahmed.m/Desktop/modify.txt';

1. create your table structure laod data back from file

LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourFilePathWIthFileName' INTO TABLE tableName
eg:
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/ahmed.m/Desktop/modify.txt' INTO TABLE asdf