# The simplest way to remove duplicate rows in t-sql

Tags: t-sql

What is the simplest way of removing duplicates from table in T-SQL query?

Columns are A and B.

Oneliners are most welcome.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: create temp table and fill with distinct rows then dump table and refill from the temp table. NOTE, not a long term solution but for a one off it's quick and dirty

Comment: owen79, thats very nice idea, gimme the code also based on the specs wilya? :D

Comment: Yep, use this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fdb8/1

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        A VARCHAR(10),
        B VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('1','1'),
('1','2'),
('2','2'),
('1','1'),
('1','2'),
('2','2')

SELECT  *
FROM    @TABLE

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY A,B) ROWID
        FROM    @TABLE
)
DELETE
FROM    Vals
WHERE   ROWID > 1

SELECT  *
FROM    @TABLE
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2821/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT A, B, count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Not seeing how this will remove the duplicates. Yeah you can use this to fill a temp table while you clear the table. But how does this answer the question you asked?

Answer (score 1):

**[how to remove duplicate values from MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496614/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-mysql-table)**

```
DELETE a FROM tbl a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id, name
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY name
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.name = b.name
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The following sql will do the job

```
DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE(a Varchar(100),b VarChar(100))

INSERT INTO @TEMP (a,b)
SELECT A,B FROM MY_Table
GROUP BY A, b

DELETE My_Table

INSERT INTO My_Table (a, b)
SELECT a, b
FROM @temp

SELECT * FROM My_Table
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fdb8/1